# Haar condition and double zeros

Tags: approximation-theory

I wonder if the space $\mathcal{A}=\text{span}\{ x_{0}, x_{2}\}$ where ($x_{i}(t)=t^i$ for all $t\in [0,1]$) is a Haar space?
I know that the Haar condition says that the only way an element in $\mathcal{A}$ can have 2 zeros or more is if it's equal to the zero element. In this case $x_{2}$ is in the space but it has a double zero. I'm not sure if it is considered a Haar space or not since the zeros aren't distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking a determinantal condition $$\left|\begin{matrix}1&1\\x&y\end{matrix}\right|\ne 0$$ for any $x,y\in[0,1]$ s.t. $x\ne y$, we arrive at $\{1,x^2\}$ is a Chebyshev system on $[0,1]$, because $y^2-x^2=0\iff x=y$. A linear span of a Chebyshev system is a Haar space. Then a double zero of $x^2$ at the endpoint does not violate a Haar property.

Comment: Sorry I meant on the interval $[0,1]$, I will change that! Does the conclusion still hold?

Comment: I have changed my answer a bit. Yes, the conclusion holds.

Comment: Great, thank you! But what if the only element that didnt satisfy the haar condition was an element that had a double zero (or multiple non-distinct zeros)? Does that count as a "violation" of the Haar condition?

Comment: Yes, it does. Observe that if we have one such element, then we have in fact infinitely many in a span because of linear combinations.

Comment: I have one objection though: $\frac{1}{2} -x^2=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} -x)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +x)$ have only one zero in $[0,1]$!

Comment: You are right. :) Such polynomials do have symmetric roots. Let's check determinantal condition. We arrive at $y^2-x^2\ne 0$ for any $x\ne y\in[0,1]$. We have $y^2-x^2=0\iff x=y$, so, it ir really a Haar space. Using this determinant I have checked that $\{1,x^2\}$ is a Chebyshev system on $[0,1]$ This is enough for $\mathcal{A}$ to be a Haar space. What about a double zero of $x^2$? Seems not to violate Haar-property on $[0,1]$. But it is a problem on, say, $[-1,1]$.

Comment: I have changed my answer once more.

Answer (score 1):

a) In $C[0,1]$ as explained earlier (by determinant property) ${A}$ satisfies Haar condition.
also note that fn has at most one distict zero
b) In $C[-1,1]$, ${A}$ doest not satisfy Haar condition because the determinant is zero for $t_{1}= -1, t_{2}=1$ ,
also not fn it two distict zeros